# Inconsistent performance results between Cloudflare and Webpagetest

Tags: performance, apache, nginx, cloudflare

I installed Nginx as a reverse proxy to work with Apache. Then I try to test and compare the performance of Nginx and Apache.

One performance data come from "Analytics & Logs > Performance > Average Response Time without Argo(Last 48 hours)". This is the response time between Cloudflare and my server.

The result:

```
Apache: 810ms
Nginx: 1220ms
```

Another performance data comes from Webpagetest. I use the following script to perform the test for Nginx:

```
setDns www.sample.com ##.##.##.##
navigate https://www.sample.com:443
```

and the following for Apache(Apache listens to port 8443):

```
setDns www.sample.com ##.##.##.##
navigate https://www.sample.com:8443
```

Then for most of the cases, **Nginx will be better than Apache**.

So the performance data from two sources are inconsistent. Why?

Comment: Oh gosh there can be so much involved with performance tuning.  I’m sure you think you’ve laid out the situation well.  I’m assuming you’re not including internet traffic in your analysis.  Once you start to make the differences in your tests smaller and smaller the root cause typically pops out.